# android edittext can not fetch data

Tags: android

In my android program I am using **achartengine** library for showing a pie chart.

The basic of the program is I have an activity,where I have 2 edit text fields and a button.after fill up the edit text field ,when click the button it will show a popup window with piechart..

here,I am using **NAME_LIST** as a string type array. where value of edit text will store and after we can fetch..
the code is given below:---

```
   public class AndroidPopupWindowActivity111_new extends Activity {

    private static int[] COLORS = new int[] { Color.MAGENTA, Color.CYAN };  
    LinearLayout layout;

    private CategorySeries mSeries = new CategorySeries("");  
    private DefaultRenderer mRenderer = new DefaultRenderer();  
    private GraphicalView mChartView;  


     EditText name1,name2;



    private  int[] VALUES = { 40,60 };
     String x1,y1;

     String[] NAME_LIST ; 

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.popup_main);
        name1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.ext1);
       name2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.ext2);
       x1=name1.getText().toString();
       y1=name2.getText().toString();
       NAME_LIST = new String[] { x1 , y1 };

        mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
        mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(100, 50, 50, 50));  
        mRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);  
        mRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);  
        mRenderer.setLegendTextSize(15);  
        mRenderer.setMargins(new int[] { 20, 30, 15, 0 });  
        mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);  
        mRenderer.setStartAngle(90);

        final Button btnOpenPopup = (Button)findViewById(R.id.openpopup);

        mChartView = ChartFactory.getPieChartView(this, mSeries, mRenderer); 


        btnOpenPopup.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
   LayoutInflater layoutInflater    = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext()  .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  


       View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.main_piechart, null);  
             final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow( popupView, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);  
             layout = (LinearLayout)popupView.findViewById(R.id.chart); 
             layout.addView(mChartView);

             for (int i = 0; i < VALUES.length; i++) {  


                    mSeries.add(NAME_LIST[i] + "(" + VALUES[i]+"%)", VALUES[i]);
                    SimpleSeriesRenderer renderer = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();  
                 renderer.setColor(COLORS[(mSeries.getItemCount() - 1) % COLORS.length]);  
                 mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);  
                 }  

                 if (mChartView != null) {  

                    mChartView.repaint();  

                 }  


             Button btnDismiss = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.dismiss);
             btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {

      popupWindow.dismiss();
     }});

             popupWindow.showAsDropDown(btnOpenPopup, 50, -30);

   }});
    }

}
```

But the problem is the name is not fetching from edittext..I am giving an example what error is occuring.:--

[Click the picture to know the problem](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-PyywxSgVUcs/UUpC-1cmH_I/AAAAAAAAAGw/u980pKTf6LY/s1600/device-2013-03-21-041707.png)...in this picture **A,B,C,D** is the edit text values..in my output **A,B,C,D** is showing as **"null"**
where is the problem??????????thanks in advance

Comment: fill the array and loop after in button click

Comment: I have also done this..but still nothing fetching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're initializing

```
String[] NAME_LIST = new String[] { x1,y1 };
```

x1 and y1 are null. Changing the values of x1 and y1 later will not change the values in NAME_LIST.

Add the line

```
NAME_LIST = new String[] { x1,y1 };
```

just before the for loop in OnCreate(). It will work.

EDIT:

Move these five lines

```
       name1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.ext1);
       name2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.ext2);
       x1=name1.getText().toString();
       y1=name2.getText().toString();
       NAME_LIST = new String[] { x1 , y1 };
```

into the onClick() method, just before the for loop begins.

Comment: Can you show where you added the line in the code snippet in your question?

Comment: Make my change, and also move the entire code block beginning with the line name1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.ext1); up to the end of the for loop inside your onClickListener's onClick() function.

Comment: I have edited my code..You can see there..but..though I am not getting the edit text values..